# Source media support

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

The latest Tor Browser update seems to have disabled streaming video using Adobe flash, resulting in the message "Media not supported on browser. Error code: source media support." The same happened when I updated Tor on a second computer. Is this a glitch in the updated Tor browser? Is there a way I can return to the previous version?

Comment: Flash Player is disabled by default in the Tor Browser because it does not route traffic through Tor. By using Flash Player, an attacker can see your real IP address, and link any Tor traffic back to you. Of course, it's perfectly fine to use Flash Player if you're using Tor as a proxy to access blocked sites, and don't care if an attacker can see your real IP.

Answer (score 1):

Tor browser bundle does not use flash in the browser bundle, it seems to me that you previously had it installed manually (which is not recommended), then the updater naturally overwrites those settings.

Flash is insecure and is not included in the tor browser bundle.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBFlash

Comment: True, but I use flash (it asks for permission) to access news sources that are embargoed in my country. At all other times I maintain anonymity. The flash player is still shown as a plug-in but doesn't work in the latest iteration of the bundle, though previous updates left it untouched. I'll try some tweaks and see if I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a plugin that requires the *separate binary executable container* to run it, and this fact - regardless of the old NSAPI and other issues - is a big problem and leak source. Unless you're using an isolated and fully-routed VM - you should disable **all** plugins of such kind, not just Adobe Flash